# Regular expression replace html entity back to characters

Tags: php, mysql, regex

In PHP with MySQL, I need to convert specific html entities like <p> back to html for specific tags. The purpose is to allow users to render specific html tags like <p> and not <script>.

I need the page to render this:
`<p>paragraph</p>break&lt;script&gt;alert(document.cookie);&lt;/script&gt;`

Given this string:
`&lt;p&gt;paragraph&lt;/p&gt;break&lt;script&gt;alert document.cookie);&lt;/script&gt;`

I tried preg_replace.

This is the regex I tried:
`$bodyText = preg_replace('^&lt;p&gt;$', '<p>', $bodyText);`

I tried to convert <p> back to this:
`<p>paragraph</p>break&lt;script&gt;alert(document.cookie);&lt;/script&gt;`

But I get this error:
`Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '^' found`

What is the best way to convert specific escaped tags back to html?

Comment: No idea what your actual question really is. Why aren't you just using standard PHP functions for html entity encoding / decoding? E.g [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) and [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: @Jonnix they want to have `&lt;p&gt;` translated back to `<p>`, but leave `&lt;script&gt;` as it is …

Comment: @misorude Well.... that's pretty horrible :P. New suggestion for OP, be more particular about what you're storing in the DB and where (admittedly a bit vague).

Comment: _“The purpose is to allow users to render specific html tags like <p> and not <script>”_ – don’t even start messing around with stuff like that yourself, that’s bound to leave holes to be exploited somewhere … Use something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) instead, that gives you very fine-grained control over what you want to allow and what not. (You need to handle _attributes_ as well, for example - otherwise I give you `<p onfocus="...">` and get my JS code executed that way, despite the fact that you naively thought “paragraphs are safe”.)

Comment: Misorude, great answer. I didn't know about HTML Purifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), no need to involve regex.

```
<?php
$source_str = "&lt;p&gt;paragraph&lt;/p&gt;break&lt;script&gt;alert document.cookie);&lt;/script&gt;";
$allowed_encoded = ["&lt;p&gt;", "&lt;/p&gt;"];
$allowed_plain = ["<p>", "</p>"];

echo str_replace($allowed_encoded, $allowed_plain, $source_str);
?>
```

Comment: Artog, thanks for the solution, the other suggestions are good too but it was exactly what I was looking for and works simply and like a charm! This is my first time using your forum and I am really impressed by the speed and sincerity of the help that you all gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = array();
$pattren = "/&lt;p&gt;/";
$p_c = array(
    $pattren => function($match) {
        $ret = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $match[0]);
        $ret = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $ret);
        return $ret;
    }

);
$res3 = preg_replace_callback_array($p_c, $bodyText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '^' found` says it: You chose `^` as the *delimiter* of the pattern, so you have to put `^` instead of `$` also at the end; you surely don't want to denote the beginning and end of string here with metacharacters `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 0):

`html_entity_decode()` undoes what `htmlentities()` did.